# How to fix "Cannot find setup.h" error when building wxWidgets-3.1.2 project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

When building a wxWidgets-3.1.2 project in Visual Studio (both the template from Nuget and the sample from the wxWidgets directory), the compiler generates the following error:

> Error C1083   Cannot open include file:  '../../../lib/vc_dll/mswud/wx/setup.h': No such file or directory    Project1    c:\wxwidgets-3.1.2\include\msvc\wx\setup.h  125

I already built the wxWidgets DLLs in VS so that's not the problem.

I cannot fix this since the file location is in the wxWidgets source code and I don't want to modify that source code. But I really need to compile my project. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had built the release DLLs but not the debug DLLs. So that was my mistake. After I built the debug DLLs I was able to compile the application.

Answer (score 1):

When building wxWidgets, wxWidgets creates (copies) `setup.h` in `$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib\mswud\wx\setup.h` with `$(WXWIN)` the directory where you installed wxWidgets.

You need to add the directory `$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib\mswud` to the Additional Include Directories in Visual Studio.

Comment: Adding the directories manually works, but it is _not_ the recommended approach to build applications using wxWidgets, there is now a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your application to use wxWidgets correctly. As the [installation instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.2/docs/msw/install.md#msw_builds_apps) say:

If you use MSVS 2010 or later IDE for building your project, simply add `wxwidgets.props` property sheet to (all) your project(s) using wxWidgets.

If you do this, you won't have any problems.